# setting up socket.io listener?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm trying to set up a server with heroku. I have my html being pushed through the port and everything is running well. Now I'm trying to implement socket.io with express.js and I'm getting 404 error on my client side. I'm new to this and don't quite understand how it's all suppose to work. Do I create a new port for each socket? If not, how can I set the listener properly? If I want multiple connections to my server does this mean I need a new socket and a new listener for each connection?

```js
var express = require('express'), http = require('http');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var server = http.createServer(app); //socket
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server); //socket

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');//website fetch
console.log(bodyParser);

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000)); //this sets the port in heroku and defaults to 5000 on local

//body parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());//website fetch
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));//website fetch
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));//website fetch

// viewed at http://localhost:5000
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/index.html'));
});

io.on('connection',function(data){ //socket
  console.log("CONNECTION"); //socket
});
server.listen(); //!!!!NOT SURE WHAT TO PUT HERE!!!!<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

// app.listen(5000);
app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script>var socket = io()</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of your code:

```
...
server.listen(); // REMOVE THIS LINE

// Change this:
app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});

// By this:

server.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

Now, you should be able to stablish a connection from your browser.

There's no need to use several ports, when a client arrives, the server will keep a connection for every client, you can test it by using several browsers sessions.